# Replace innerHtml with case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting a blog post html content as a string from a CMS using a REST API. I am using CK editor to write the post content. If I use a `code` tag in ck editor, it generates this HTML string.

```html
  <pre>
    <code class="language-python">
      a = 1 + 2
    </code>
  </pre>
```

I am taking the above string and replacing the `pre code` tags with string `SyntaxHighlighter` so that I can highlight the syntax in react. It is a custom tag used by react-syntax-highlighter library to highlight the syntax and I stored it in a string "postContent". The string looks like this after the conversion.

```js
<SyntaxHighlighter language="python" style={dark}>
a = 1 + 2
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

I pass this string to react Post component which then renders the HTML content.

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.postContent }}>
```

I have tried react-html-parser as well. Both of these methods, convert "SyntaxHighlighter" to "syntaxhighlighter" breaking the code.

How can I preserve the case, if not possible, are there any other methods to achieve my purpose?

Comment: A more complete example might be helpful - for example, what is `props.postContent`?  Does that equal your `<SyntaxHighlighter>...</SyntaxHighlighter>` block?  Are you doing any processing on it in between these two lines?  For what reason do you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to begin with?  What do you mean by "breaking the code" - runtime errors?  Compiler errors?  Just unintended output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SyntaxHighlighter` is a React component, so it won't work if you blat it into place using `dangerousSetInnerHTML` – that works with HTML, not JSX.

You're on the right track with `react-html-parser` – you can parse the content from the post, and then transform the `<code>` fragments using its delightful [`transform` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser#transform-function), which lets you intercept any node and provide a replacement element:

```js
function transform(node) {
  if (node.type === "tag" && node.name === "code") {
    return (
      <SyntaxHighlighter language="python" style={dark}>
        {node.children[0].data}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    );
  }
}

// ReactHtmlParser(testInput, { transform })
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-lake-y8tljl?file=/src/App.js)